# Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.212.0.14:44

Tags: azure, deployment, service, azure-appservice

We are getting the below error Azure App Service Deploy task  when we deploy to app service using pipeline.

2022-07-28T12:06:20.9763974Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2022-07-28T12:06:20.9768488Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.212.0.14:443

can you please share any pointers to this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following workarounds to resolve this type of errors in Azure App Services:

- Check whether is there any application setting called as `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM` in Azure App Service.
- Make sure to add it and set its value to `true` incase If it exists, if not add that application setting.
- Then try to Restart and redeploy the application in the Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying to an ASE, Inspect the NSG settings tied to the ASE subnet for any recently added rules that might restrict inbound/outbound traffic.
Modifying the problematic NSG rule to allow essential outbound connectivity, including access to the ASE endpoints and the SCM site's IP address fixed the issue for me